# RS 232 Communication for embeded devices

Tags: java-me, serial-port

I have 2 embeded devices that will have to communicate via RS232. Lets say that device A will send and receive data via RS232. I need to program device A in JAVA ME. Is there a class or library i can use? I searched the internet and found two libraries: RxTx and JavaComm. But i'm not sure if i can use them in a Java ME project? Is it possible and do you recommend it? Or is there an another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use rxtx in java ME project and I will recommend rxtx over javax.comm as javax.comm works only on windows but rxtx works on both linux and windows.